# Is disrespecting alignment requirements undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, alignment

Picture I'm developing for an embedded device so I interact with hardware addresses directly.

I have a `uint16_t` and I write it to address `0x10001` using `(uint16_t*)(0x10001) = myShort;`.

What happens in practice on common architectures ? What are the guarantees ?

What if I then try to read it using `uint16_t myShortOrIsIt = *((uint16_t*)(0x10001));` ?

Comment: Define "common architectures". Some can handle this, some will crash. Generally UB means exactly NO guarantees for anything.

Comment: That depends on the architecture. Possibilities include not having a problem, reduced performance, or only having an issue (e.g., fault or performance hit) if the unaligned access spans a cache line.

Comment: You should check the compiler you are using for the embedded system to see. Also look at the assembly code generated to verify. Portability is secondary.

Comment: Sounds like your embedded device does not have an alignment requirement.  If it does, you might want to use assembly to do the hardware interaction.

Comment: @Eljay How would coding this in assembler help?

Comment: According to the C++ standard, the behaviour is undefined.    Practically, some architectures will cause the program to terminate abnormally,   others will work fine but with reduced performance.    Messing with alignment (or structure padding) on the latter platforms generally involve a trade-off between performance and use of memory - and the trade-off varies with architecture.

Comment: @PaulSanders • One platform I worked on could only read-or-write in 32-bit words.  All fine and good, but to write a byte it'd have to read the word, mask and shift the byte into the word, and write the word back to memory.  Not a problem for the C++ code, until that memory was memory mapped I/O registers, and then that caused a big problem.  Wrote the interfacing code in assembly to work around the problem.  Probably could have written the same assembly in clever C++ code, but at the time it was the path of least resistance.